# Why is the same fileID use to search files in google drive fail on realtime api?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I got the fileID from a file and it works when I try to search it. But, when I try to use the same fileID to do `gapi.drive.realtime.load(fileID, onFileLoaded, initializeModel);` it returns an error `404 (Not Found)  Drive Realtime API Error: not_found: Document not found: 1mxRMHav-jizEbupALjUb9F16dzdzdfuUPw83AxC3ip0`.
I'm sure that the file id is correct since I'm able to pull out its information such as owners, filesize, filename, etc.

This only happen when the file type is google document; the id works fine if its a plain text file. Does the google document function differently then other type of file?

Comment: what is your auth scope?

Comment: the scope is https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

Comment: is the fileid for a google document file suppose to have a different format than a none google document file?