# Google Doc Script onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs, add-on

I want to build a Google Doc Extension.

Google Spreadsheets has an onEdit trigger, Google Documents don't seem to: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers

Is there a way for me to handle user input (typing) cleanly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in Apps Script. If you write an app using the Drive API, you can use the Realtime API https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/

Comment: Now struggling with the same issue as [this person.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17896313/why-is-the-same-fileid-use-to-search-files-in-google-drive-fail-on-realtime-api)
Any idea what could be causing it?