# Google Docs Add On onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

Google Apps has some simple triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

One of which is onEdit. As documented, onEdit fires for Google Spreadsheets, but it does not fire for Google Docs.

Is there a clean way to detect when the user has changed the document, and run a script when that happens?

Comment: I don't know anything about this API, but it looks like it might be worth taking a look at:  [Files Watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/watch)

Comment: Files Watch API is the one if you are not forced to used Apps script for your work. Btw, another similar q/a - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781406/google-doc-script-onedit

Comment: you might also be interested in reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24773177/how-to-poll-a-google-doc-from-an-add-on/24773178#24773178)

Answer (score 5):

This is not a complete answer, but this may (not sure) help you based on your actual requirement.
You can have a function like this and then using installed triggers you can call this function every minute to poll document and check whether someone has edited it or not.

```
 function isEdited()
    {
      var MyDoc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
      var Text = MyDoc.editAsText().getText();
      var DocLen= Text.length;
      if(DocLen!= PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty('DocLen'))
      {
        CallYourFunction();
        PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty('DocLen', DocLen)
      }    
    }
```

Is 60 sec delay okey in your service... 60 sec is the maximum delay that can occur here.

Comment: Hello Anees, see also the post I linked to in question's comment, the update delay is about 2 seconds but it's not as simple as your solution of course. (upvoted yours for its simplicity)

Comment: Thanks Serge, thats' a realtime solution..... i was also looking for a such a kind of solution, I too was facing this 60 sec delay issue and was not sure on what to do next... Hey dylanjha, consider the one Serge pointed and not mine.... :-)