# Is it possible to run a function in Google App Scripts after a document is finished saving?

Tags: google-apps-script

So let's say I have a Google Document. When you type things in a Google Document, there is an automatic save feature. I was wondering if it is possible to run a function in the script editor after a document is finished saving?

Comment: You can run a script anytime you want.  But there is not an after save trigger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Doc Script onEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781406/google-doc-script-onedit)

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*There is no API endpoint **nor** Apps Script trigger that you can use to get the information that the content of a Google Doc has changed or saved.*

#### More Information:

There is no Apps Script method which runs on Document save - an `onEdit()` trigger does not even exist in Apps Script for Google Docs - I presume this is because edits are ***constantly saved*** and so with an `onEdit()` trigger API requests would be constantly firing.

#### References:

- [Google Apps Script - Simple Triggers - Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions)
- [Google Apps Script - Available types of triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers)
- [Google Docs > API v1 - Usage limits](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/limits)